# Automate logon by USB

Tags: login

I often need to login to a very large number of pcs (win 10) using the local Admin Account. I was wandering if there is a way to do it automatically by plugging an usb. In my environment I don't have security risk.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way is by using [Predator](https://www.predator-usb.com/predator/en/index.php), which is an automated software, however I believe it only works on a logged on administrator user, as I haven't tried it out yet.

Another way, which I think is recommended is by using [Rohos Logon Key](http://www.rohos.com/products/rohos-logon-free/) with a free version, which I wouldn't recommend for security purposes, as the paid version really benefits. According to MakeUseOf, one of the screenshots, as displayed below:

[image: Setup]

shows you can select a specific user.

Finally, I just want to say that I don't believe there is a way *yet* to automatically logon to multiple PCs using 1 USB inside one PC. The USB will need to be individually plugged into the PCs.

Hope this helps,

Thanks,

yg.swagness

Comment: Thanks yg.swagness, plugging the USB  to individually PCs was my intention (won't be a problem). I have already seen the software you have suggested but they are not suitable for me as because other users need to logon to these PCs.

Comment: Ok @MarcS. But are you trying to say that if you plug it in, it uses the local admin account and if removed, it switches back to the other user's account?